# EU-citizen working as contractor in Switzerland?

Tags: contracts, registration, switzerland

If I'm an EU-citizen and want to work in Switzerland as contractor, what should I do, if I have company registered in EU?

1. Can I work in Switzerland as contractor and invoice my client company as EU-registered company? Or I'm required to register company in Switzerland?
2. If registering a company in Switzerland is required, do I need special permission from Swiss government to do that?

Comment: This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Comment: @ColorWP.com you want to close all questions targeting specific country? I think you're going to kill this proposal

Comment: I absolutely agree it's on-topic. Many sample Q's on [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37227?phase=definition) are country-specific.

Comment: No, please, **this is not at all what is meant by "too localized."** There's nothing about the practice of an entire country/state/city/community that would be considered "too localized." This close reason is being severely reworked because of these misunderstandings (more on that soon) — but it almost never makes sense to close a question because it pertains to a specific country — http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42408/change-the-text-of-too-localized-in-the-meta-close-reasons/87416#87416

Answer (score 2):

I am not a lawyer or an expert on the issue, but it would be very strange if a company in a reputable Western country X (i.e. not under embargo or similar) could not provide services to and bill a company in a reputable Western country Y. If a Swiss company wants to import goods from abroad, does the company they're buying from need to register a company in Switzerland? Sounds unlikely.

If the deal requires you to work on-site, you might need to get a work permit, depending on how long you'll stay in the country.

Comment: The difference is, when you are working as contractor, your domicile is on the territory of that country. And usually each country requires that their residents pay taxes by them.